# Spectron and starting electron application

Tags: mocha.js, electron, pouchdb, spectron

While trying to run the first mocha test for my electron application I get error:

[image]

I am pretty sure it is related to the way application is run in general. While using "electron ." to start, there is no issue. When "npm start" is executed, i get the same error as pictured. Most probably it is related to the way db was added to electron (PouchDB + sqlite) for Windows (recompilation)

Since configuring sqlite for PouchDB for electron took me a while and I have to use this tool, do you think there is a way to get mocha running under such circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should use "npm start", I started a cmd window under the dir where the mocha test is written, and just run "mocha" and the test runs.